# Spinner default adapter type from xml and code

Tags: android

When I give the values to my spinner from `xml` array it is ok.

```
android:entries="@array/array"
```

But now I want to give the value from code like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adp= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,array);
            patientSpiner.setAdapter(adp);
```

But the design is different.
So what parameter do I have to set for getting the same result? `simple_spinner_item` does not help

Comment: Try adding adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

Comment: Glad it did :) , should have posted as an answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to call

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

on the adapter before you set it on the spinner.

Answer (score 1):

You must set the DropDownViewResource for the Spinner. It's usually simple_spinner_dropdown_item at android.R.layout- or else you choose / create.